# Опция назначения хоткеев

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Как можно реализовать настройку горячих клавиш для пользователя (т.е. я хочу чтоб пользовать мог сам задать сочетание клавиш на определенное действие)?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

[статья 1](https://myrusakov.ru/javascript-hotkey.html)
[статья 2](https://habr.com/ru/post/19003/)

Может это Вам чем-то поможет, а в целом, я не знаю, но скорей всего Вам поможет input для пользователя, где он будет вводить сочетание клавиш, а вы эти клавиши сохраняете в localStorage и оттуда каждый раз подтягиваете в сваю функцию, где у вас логика hotkey, так получится, что у каждого пользователя будут свои собственные настройки hotkey